# Sqlalchemy - copy data from a database to another database with exactly same schema

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 mysql database connect with sqlalchemy in 2 docker machine.

They both have same schema and data inside.

Now I want to copy data in 1 of the database to another to merge 2 mysql database into 1. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

Run this on the database you want to copy over:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info {yourdbname} > {yourdbname}.sql
```

And then on the database you want to import this:

```
mysql {yourdbname} < {yourdbname}.sql
```

You might run into an issue with the primary keys and/or duplicate records. Sadly from that point on you will have to generate SQL to export your data with an altered primary key, while keeping your foreign key relations intact.

This second complex issue a procedure is required to query the information schema:

- Select the table names from the information schema
- Select the primary key using the information schema
- Select max(primary key) for every table.
- Use the information schema to create SELECT queries in which you add the previous max(primary key) to the primary key, and write the output to the data file.

On foreign keys related you will also have to add this same max(primary key) value from the related table. 
It will be a bit more code to write, but 50-80 lines stored procedure should do it.

Comment: is it possible in my case since i have 2 database in 2 docker machines

Comment: Seriously depends on your data.

Comment: that mysqldump will create a file call {mydatabase}.sql then i can take that file to another docker machine and do the second command you said. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. I think I will face that duplicate primary key problem since there is duplicate id for columns. what is the good strategy to do so tho?

Comment: See my update (you have to write a bit of code to solve this, but is can be done)

Comment: I guess i just done the first issue. for the second issue I dont really get you. can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, the second part requires a good amount of code to be written. I can not do that on stackoverflow (too much time involved, takes a few hours).

Comment: is there any tool that you can suggest me to use?

Comment: There are commercial tools available, to do this, however I think writing it yourself will be faster (even despite a learning curve).