# sqlalchemy python select and insert

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

i have following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine1 = create_engine('mysql://user:password@host1/schema', echo=True)
engine2 = create_engine('mysql://user:password@host2/schema')

connection1 = engine1.connect()
connection2 = engine2.connect()

table1 = connection1.execute("select * from table1")
table2 = connection2.execute("select * from table2")
```

Now i want to insert all entries from this `table1` into an identical empty table `table2` in `connection2`.

How can i achive that?

I could also create a `dict` out of `table1` and insert it then into `table2`. As i learned from the documentation of sqlalchemy there is a way to do that, but the examples there assume that you create a whole new table in order to insert into it with `new_table.insert()`. It doesnt work for my existing tables.

Thanks

Comment: In your example `table2` is a `ResultProxy`, not a table.

Comment: That is true. What should i change in order to achive my requirements?

Comment: You could for example reflect *table2* and insert, or use the syntactic constructs `table()` and `column()` for query building. Since *table2* exists already, reflection might be the simpler approach. But are you sure you want to use SQLAlchemy for this, instead of [MySQL's own tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712049/sqlalchemy-copy-data-from-a-database-to-another-database-with-exactly-same-sch)?